# Http Post attribute does not work in mvc core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have the following action in my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int  id)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated != true)
            return NotFound();


        var customers= await _context.CUSTOMERS.FindAsync(id);
        _context.CUSTOMERS.Remove(customers);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();



        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

and I have a scaffolded Index view, where I want to call the Delete button

```
  <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.CB_ROWID">Delete</a>
```

and I get

This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44386/Customers/Delete/6
HTTP ERROR 404

if I remove the [HttpPost] attribute from my action things work fine, any advice tips? anything ?=)

Comment: The anchor tag always sending HTTP request using GET method, hence `[HttpPost]` attribute is unnecessary. If you want to use POST, you need to use normal form submit.

Comment: Is it bad if I leave it as it is then?

Comment: Use [HttpDelete] Attribute instead of  [HttpPost]

Comment: Just removing `[HttpPost]` or using `[HttpDelete]` is fine. But if you really want to use POST, use AJAX (e.g. `$.post()`) and place the redirect URL using `location.href` because you cannot use `RedirectToAction()` with AJAX call.

Comment: HttpDelete does not work either, my only concern is is it safe not HttpPost or HttpDelete